# Не правильно работает переход из пуша

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notification

Использую FirebaseMessagingService.
В методе `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` создаю `Notification` и устанавливаю для него `setContentIntent`. Если приложение находится на переднем плане, то переход по пушу срабатывает правильно. Но если приложение находится в фоне или закрыто, то переход по пушу перекидывает на главную активность приложения.
Как сделать чтобы переход по пушу перекидывал на заданную активность во всех случаях?

Код метода обратного вызова `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "body" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    String type = data.get("type");
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    switch (type) {
        case "telecast":
            String title = data.get("title");
            int channelId = Integer.valueOf(data.get("channel_id"));
            int programId = Integer.valueOf(data.get("program_id"));
            boolean isFavorite = data.containsKey("favorite") ? Boolean.valueOf(data.get("favorite")) : false;

            intent = ProgramActivity.newIntent(this, title, channelId, programId, TAG_PROGRAM, isFavorite, 0);
            intent.setPackage("ru.arealidea.vsetv.App");
            break;
        case "film":
            int id = Integer.valueOf(data.get("id"));

            intent = new Intent(this, FilmsInfoActivity.class).putExtra("id", id);
            break;
        case "podcast":
            int podcast_id = Integer.valueOf(data.get("podcast_id"));
            int episode_id = Integer.valueOf(data.get("episode_id"));

            intent = new Intent(this, PodcastInfoActivity.class).putExtra("id", podcast_id);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, remoteMessage.hashCode(), intent, 0);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(remoteMessage.hashCode(), notification);
}
```

Активности в манифесте:

```
<activity android:name=".App.Activity.ProgramActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".App.Activity.PodcastInfoActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".App.Activity.FilmsInfoActivity"/>
```